# Green LED always on, but everything seems to be normal?

Tags: led

Raspberry Pi 4 (8GB)

Ubuntu 20.04 (booting from USB, no SD card)

---

My green LED is constantly on, but everything seems to be running fine. I initially thought it may be because I'm seeding with Deluge, but when I stopped seeding the green LED still remains on. It's constantly solid and only blinks once every minute or two for 1-2 seconds and then returns to solid green.

Here are the Docker containers that I'm running:

- Bazarr
- Bitwarden
- Deluge
- Jackett
- Jellyfin
- Komga
- Nextcloud
- MariaDB
- Redis
- Portainer
- Radarr
- Sonarr
- Traefik
- Watchtower
- Wireguard

Comment: `blinks once every minute or two for 1-2 seconds` ... so, the LED is not always on

Comment: Unless you have changed the board led configuration (you can change what the green led means by a setting in `config.txt`) I would assume that your Pi is just overloaded and therefore constantly accesses the drive. I'm not sure what the LED does when no SD card is in the slot, though.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you've not supplied enough information to answer the question you've asked. Consequently, all you're likely to get for it is opinions; here's mine:

- Do some [more research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=raspberry+pi+4+solid+green+led&t=ffnt&ia=web)
- Recall the [flicker fusion threshold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold), and recognize that you can't tell the difference between `constantly on` and a light that is turning on and off at a rate above the threshold.
- Understand that all of ]that software you've brought on board may be controlling the green led](https://www.heelpbook.net/2021/raspberry-pi-controlling-pwr-and-act-leds-red-and-green-leds/); i.e. use the process of elimination for each of your apps.
- Check `/etc/fstab` (or wherever Ubuntu stores this information) to see how your USB is mounted. Look for the line where your root filesystem `/` is mounted. If you don't see the `noatime` option, you may try adding it - perhaps like so:

```
PARTUUID=7f4939b6-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```